# Any benefits of sun-java over openjdk on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu, java

Are there any benefits of running Sun's java on Ubuntu 10.04 -- over the default openjdk, or is this a legacy issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using AWT/Swing applications, then you're better with Sun/Oracle's Java.

Comment: why, can you expand a bit?

Comment: Mysterious strange bugs. Give it a try, take any non-trivial AWT/Swing application and look what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Some apps don't like openjdk. For example, try running BlueJ in openjdk.